# Android Studio - Code Inspection - Spelling

Tags: java, android

When i **warning regarding spelling mistake**  , i got a option like the following screenshot.
[image]

Then i **added *Bootup* to dictionary & Warning gone**.Is there any problem in doing so.Like , IDE change or any other configuration change ?

If it will causes problem how **can i revert that** (To remove from Dictionary) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be ok with custom dict.

Go to File -> Settings -> Editor -> Spelling. There you can remove your custom words.